# php DateTime countdown

Tags: php, datetime

So I have a question about a DateTime in php.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-02-01 10:40:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-03 19:13:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%d day %h hours %i minutes');
```

What echo outputs is: 2day 8hours 33minutes. 
Ok I know that the difference between first and the second variable is equal to the output. But is there any way that the output could be some sort of count down.

For example:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-01-01 13:30:00');
```

What I want to be output is: 13:30:00, and 2 minutes later there would be 13:28:00.

Is there any way to be done that with diff function.

Thanks for help

Sebastian

Comment: So you want the amount of time displayed on the browser screen to update without reloading the page?

Comment: why not develop custom php function for that?

Comment: no it doesn't need to be refreshed automaticlly. i only want the timer closer to 0 everytime i refresh

Answer (score 3):

This will only work if:

- one of the times in now
- the page refreshes or you use ajax. PHP is executed on the server-side.

So you basically already have the code with just a tweak:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-03 19:13:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%d day %h hours %i minutes');
```

Comment: Will it really *only* work using AJAX? An alternative would be to provide the times to the client - and then let the client perform the countdown in a loop, right?

Comment: Doing it with JavaScript on the clientside would be the best way to do it if the countdown is to be updating itself every second, minute, etc. But if it only has to update when the page is loaded then doing it with PHP is probably easier.